# Rails 6 are you trying to open an SSL connection to a non-SSL Puma?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, amazon-ecs, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm trying to set up Rails on AWS ECS with HTTPS access. When my ECS Service is deployed, these are the logs:

```
=> Rails 6.1.3.2 application starting in production
=> Booting Puma
* Listening on http://0.0.0.0:3000
* PID: 1
* Environment: production
* Max threads: 5
* Min threads: 5
* Puma version: 5.3.2 (ruby 3.0.1-p64) ("Sweetnighter")
Puma starting in single mode...
* Listening on http://0.0.0.0:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop

2021-08-06 06:21:21 +0000 HTTP parse error, malformed request: 
  #<Puma::HttpParserError: Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails. Are you trying to open an SSL connection to a non-SSL Puma?>
```

I believe the health checks are hitting the container and failing. I'm not sure why this is happening. I already set `config.force_ssl = true` in my `environments/production.rb`. Any suggestions on what I am missing?

I'm using `Rails 6.1.3.2` and `ruby 3.0.1`. Thanks!

Comment: Have you setup any nginx with your ssl certificate? Or how do you serve the SSL?

Comment: I have not setup any nginx with my SSL cert. I am using an AWS Application Load Balancer and serving my SSL cert through the load balancer.

Comment: Hey, were you able to find a solution? I'm with the same issue. Thanks